# Adding an image to button and then button click not detected

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have added a Custom button, and added a `UIImage` to it. Ever since i added the image i am unable to click the button, it takes 3-4 attempts for the click to be detected and for the code execute. Why is this ?

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 90.0, 150.0, 40.0);
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
[customView addSubview:button];
```

The buttonClick Method :

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender {
NSLog (@"Click");
}
```

Comment: When you comment out the image part, does it in fact work better? I could not think of any way an image would affect a buttons clickability ... unless the image makes you click the wrong spot??

Comment: check your customView frame. is it enough big for the button.

Comment: just tried your code, seemed to work fine, but i did `[self.view addSubview:button]`, try with `self.view` and see if there are any changes in clickability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Illep  I used your code in a demo app and added a button.png as well. The code works absolutely fine.

Since you are adding This button to a separate view i.e

```
[customView addSubview:button];
```

so there are pretty much chances that either the user interaction of this customView or The button is getting added somewhere outside the frames of your customView (though chances are pretty less). You can check this by setting clipSubView to TRUE for your customView..

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Problem could be your `customView` region, When the button not fit into it's region then you can't interact with it. As rahul suggested use clipToSubview to TRUE. Then the button will be in focus of custom view / you can log the position and sizes for compare both.Hope it helps, if not add comment again.